# Could C# Linq do combinatorics?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this data structure:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<Product>(){ { Name = "Book", Count = 40}, { Name = "Car", Count = 70}, { Name = "Pen", Count = 60}........... } // 500 product object


var productsUpTo100SumCountPropert = list.Where(.....) ????

// productsUpTo100SumCountPropert output:
// { { Name = "Book", Count = 40}, { Name = "Pen", Count = 60} }
```

I want to sum the Count properties of the collection and return only products objects where that property Count sum is less than or equal to 100.

If is not possible with linq, what is a better approach that I can use?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  I highly discourage you from posting yes/no questions or else someone might actually answer them and give you a yes/no answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What research have you done into how to use the `Where` method (your example indicates you think it's going to be a useful operator)?  There are lots of tutorials on the subject out there.  Have you read any?  Have you tried anything?  What happened in your attempts?

Comment: No answer is going to be good unless there is a better understanding of what you want. There are 3 different answer here and I don't know if any of them are what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't want a sum of propert Count, I want products that have sum of Count propert less equal 100.

Comment: @Alexsandro_xpt if you know enough about a lambdas to ask about it in the question, then what do you not understand about using it with LINQ? You have everything you need in your example code except for the lambda and the lambda is simple in this case.

Comment: @NickFreeman, I'm edited the question, I guess now, it will be more clear to understand. Thanks!

Comment: @NickFreeman, look that: https://gist.github.com/alexsandro-xpt/5620922

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the comments you've left on other peoples' answers and [your gist (link)](https://gist.github.com/alexsandro-xpt/5620922), it looks like what you're trying to solve is in fact the Knapsack Problem - in particular, the [0/1 Knapsack Problem (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem).

The Wikipedia page on this topic (that I linked to) has a short dynamic programming solution for you. It has pseudo-polynomial running time ("pseudo" because the complexity depends on the capacity you choose for your knapsack (`W`).

A good preprocessing step to take before running the algorithm is to find the greatest common denominator (`GCD`) of all of your item weights (`w_i`) and then divide it out of each value.

```
d <- GCD({w_1, w_2, ..., w_N})
w_i' <- w_i / d //for each i = 1, 2, ..., N
W' <- W / d //integer division here
```

Then solve the problem using the modified weights and capacity instead (`w_i'` and `W'`).

The greedy algorithm you use in your gist won't work very well. This better algorithm is simple enough that it's worth implementing.

Comment: Very good man! If someone would like see implementation could be see at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1#C.23

Answer (score 1):

You need the  [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) extension method

```
list.Count(p => p.Count <= 100);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the sum of the items, `Where` and `Sum` extension methods could be utilized:

```
list.Where(p => p.Count <= 100).Sum(p => p.Count);
```

Comment: Count and Sum retunr a Int value.

I don't wanna sum or count, I want the products that having his propert Count sum less or equal 100;

Comment: So are you saying that you want everything in the list as long as the whole list is <= 100?  If not, then how do we know how to "Group" the items in the list together?  Do we group them because they all have the same Name?

Comment: This the question, they haven't same name.
I think it's not possible with LINQ, I'm seek for another algorithm.

Comment: Do your list contain products with the same Name ?

Comment: No, @Uzzy, only thing I know is: Should get products where theirs Count properties sums not exceeding 100

Comment: Finally understood what do you want, do you need all possible combination? or only one best fit?

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Where(p=> p.Count <= 100).ToList();
```

Comment: No, this return only products that have Count propert less or equal 100.

I need products group that her propert Count sum be <= 100

Look:

       var products = { { Name = "Book", Count=40 }, { Name = "Car", Count=70 }, { Name = "Computer", Count=60 } };

       var p0 = products.Where(.......);

       p0; //{ { Name = "Book", Count=40 },{ Name = "Computer", Count=60 } };

Comment: @Alexsandro_xpt "I wish LINQ or Lambda sum Count properts and give me only product object where Count prop be less or equal 100." He gave you what you asked for...

Comment: So, you are looking for all possible combinations of the List<> that yield a result that is less than 100?  So { { Book }, { Book,Computer}, { Computer }, {Car}, .... } ?